# Django how to display list users with some data in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I want to display the list of users with some objects in 2 modelapps created.

these are the models.

first model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
indirizzo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
citta = models.CharField(max_length=50)
paese = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
ecap = models.CharField(max_length=4)
descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True,null=True)
```

second model:

```
class Ore(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,    related_name="ore",null=True,)
data = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
oret = models.CharField(max_length=3,)
contrattiok = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
contrattiko = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,)
nomecognome = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
```

my view:

```
def inizio(request):
users = User.objects.all() 
return render (request, "base.html", {"users":users})
```

my template:

```
  {% for users in users %}
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <img src="{{ users.userprofile.image.url }}"class="thumbnail">
  <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">{{users}}</h4>
  </td>
  <td><h4 class="small font-weight-bold">{{users.last_name}}</h4></td>
  <td class="text-center">
  <h4 class="small font-weight-bold" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">{{ users.ore.contrattiok }}</h4>     <<<<<(does not work)
  </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: the relationship `User` <-> `Ore` is a one-to-many relationship, so in your template, for a given user, you have to loop through all `Ore` instances: `{% for ore in user.ore %}<p>{{ ore.contrattiok }}</p>{% endfor %}`

Comment: does work, dont show nothing

Comment: you do `for users in users` in your template (which is really not good style you're redefining `users` and using a plural for a singular object) so maybe `for ore in users.ore` would work in this case? Just look at your code and try figure out which variable is declared with which name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw several problems in your templates.
1. It would be better to make different variable of `users` loop to increase readability code.
don't do this: `{% for users in users %}`
but instead: `{% for user in users %}`
so then you can use it with `user` instead of `users` inside loop like:
`{{ user.last_name }}`

2. your `<tbody>` inside forloop users, but theres no `</tbody>` right before the `{% endfor %}`.
But I suggest you to do not include `<tbody>` inside forloop. 
Do this instead:

```
<tbody>
{% for user in users %}
<tr><td></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

3. since your foreign key is inside Ore model instead
   (one to many relationship which means **1 user has many ores**),
   so you need to loop every ore on each user.

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% for ore in user.ore.all %}
        {{ ore.contrattiok }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

so the final result will be like this:

```
<tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}" class="thumbnail">
            <h4 class="small font-weight-bold">{{ user }}</h4>
        </td>
        <td><h4 class="small font-weight-bold">{{user.last_name}}</h4></td>
        <td class="text-center">
            {% for ore in user.ore.all %}
            <h4 class="small font-weight-bold" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
                {{ ore.contrattiok }}
            </h4>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

---

**EDITED**

based on your comment, so you want to sum the total of `contrattiok` field?
if that so, you need to change your `view` using [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards)

```
from django.db.models import Sum

users = User.objects.annotate(total_contrattiok=Sum('ore__contrattiok'))
```

then in your template:

```
{% for user in users %}
<td class="text-center">
    <h4 class="small font-weight-bold" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">
        {{ user.total_contrattiok }}
    </h4>
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hi thnx for your answer, I followed your instructions but give me an error ('RelatedManager' object is not iterable), but I have added {% for ore in user.ore.all %} and function, but it lists all the objects for each user, I wish it gives me the total. for example two object  1+1 = 2

Comment: oh yes it should be `user.ore.all`, sorry, I edited it.. what do you mean with "gives the total" ?

Comment: if you want to get the length of the list: `user.ore.all|length`

Comment: the field contrattiok contains the hours of work, {{ ore.contrattiok }}  list all the hours for all the days of the month, I want it to give me the total of all the hours of the month, not to list them

Comment: thnx i just add your code total_contrattiok=Sum and work.